# jQuery Promise, $.when execute all deferreds in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I've got some code which makes requests to two different files on my web server, and I'd like to take some action after they're done, leveraging deferreds:

```
var url = 'testDataRoot.json',
    folderUrl= 'Content/testData.json';

var root = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
})

var folder = $.ajax({
    url: folderUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
})

function getBiggest(arr) {
    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a < b;
    })
    return arr[0];
}
```

`$.when` takes a list/array of deferred:

```
$.when([root,folder]).then(function(args){
    console.log(args); // promise array
    console.log(args[0]); // first promise
    console.log(args[0]['responseText']); // this has a value in the two previous lines yet undefined here, why?
});
```

I'd like to call `getBiggest` on the response from each deferred.  I'd like a solution that would work for two deferreds, or 200.  What's the most extensible way to accomplish this?

Comment: `$.when` doesn't take an array, it accepts a variable number of arguments. What happens is actually that `$.when` revolves immediately with the array as value. Check its documentation, especially the examples http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/. The result of each promise is passed as argument to the callback.

Comment: In addition, `getBiggest` is buggy and doesn't work.

Comment: @Jon could you elaborate, please?

Comment: The comparison function you pass to `.sort` has to return 0 if both values are equal, a negative number if the first value is "smaller", and a positive number if it is "bigger". It is not supposed to retune a Boolean.

Comment: Does the "duplicate" solve your issue or is this still a problem? If it is, have you considered `.then` on each promise?